# python-3: object name as string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, object

I have the following two tables:

"table1":

```
a x1
b y1
```

"table2":

```
a x2
b y2
```

I want to open them and create the following dictionary:

```
{"table1": {"a": ["x1"]}, {"b": ["y1"]}, \
 "table2": {"a": ["x2"]}, {"b": ["y2"]}}
```

To do so, I am currently doing the following:

```
with open("table1", "r") as table1, \
    open("table2", "r") as table2:

    dictionary = {"table1": {}, \
                "table2": {}}

    for line in table1:

        col1 = line.split(" ")[0]
        col2 = line.split(" ")[1].strip()

        dictionary["table1"][col1] = col2

    for line in table2:

        col1 = line.split(" ")[0]
        col2 = line.split(" ")[1].strip()

        dictionary["table2"][col1] = col2

print(dictionary)

{'table1': {'a': 'x1', 'b': 'y1'}, 'table2': {'a': 'x2', 'b': 'y2'}}
```

My question is, how can I link the name of the opened table, e.g. table1, to the dictionary key string "table1"?

Something like this (not correct):

```
with open("table1", "r") as table1, \
    open("table2", "r") as table2:

    dictionary = dict()

    for table in [table1, table2]:

        for line in table: 

            col1 = line.split(" ")[0]
            col2 = line.split(" ")[1].strip()

            dictionary[table][col1] = col2    # HERE I WANT table TO BE "table1", NOT THE OBJECT table1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the files in a dictionary with the same keys of the other:

```py
table = dict()
with open("table1", "r") as table['table1'], \
    open("table2", "r") as table['table2']:

    dictionary = dict()

    for table_name in ['table1', 'table2']:

        for line in table[table_name]: 

            col1 = line.split(" ")[0]
            col2 = line.split(" ")[1].strip()

            dictionary[table_name]={col1:[col2]}
```